# iOS: How to insert Special like " or ' character in sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a NSString variable that includes some characters " and '.
So, how can I use it as a parameter to insert into table in Sqlite3?
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: [iOS is ***NOT*** IOS](http://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS)!

Comment: oh, my fault. Wrong type :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid formatting problems, use a parameter to pass the string into the SQL statement:

```
NSString *str = @"some characters \" and \'";
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable(Name) VALUES(?)";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"SQL execution failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"SQL prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: But characters " or ' are in my NSString variable, how to put \ ahead it?

Comment: You need to escape with \ only if you write the string directly in the source code (as in my example). Once you have a NSString, you do not need to modify it in any way if you bind it as a parameter.

Comment: if i want to update an existing value in db using a string which contains special characters like " and '

Comment: @BraneDullet Then use UPDATE.

Answer (score 4):

Escape the quote with 2 quotes. Doublequote needs no replacement

```
''
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d41d8/753)

Answer (score 1):

You can init the NSString with the special character by put the \ character before it.
For example:

```
NSString *string = @"This is \" and this is \'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the caracter automatically:

```
NSString *stringFromExternalDatabase = @"Capital of Chad is N'Djamena";
[stringFromExternalDatabase stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\'"];
```

and then would place stringFromExternalDatabase in a table.

When you retreive the stringFromExternalDatabase from the database, you do the other operation:

```
[stringFromExternalDatabase stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:@"'"];
```