# how to store double quotation marks in sqlite using iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I use sqlite data base to store values in offline mode.In these values it contains strings with double quotation marks.(eg: ***hai "Man"***)

```
NSString* insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE tablename SET SummaryDescription=\"%@\" WHERE SummaryDate1=\"%@\" AND ClientId=\"%@\"",SummaryDescription,[_dic objectForKey:@"SummaryDate1"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ClientID"]];

 [db updateTable:insertSQL];
```

In SummaryDescription contains value ***hai "Man"***.But I cannot able to store this data into database.
             If we remove this double quotation marks we can store this data.Is there is any other way to store these types of double quotation marks string.

Comment: It's a double quotation not codes. ask question with correct spelling. wrong spelling create wrong Meaning.

Comment: _Regardless_ of the values involved, do not build a sql statement manually like that -- it's susceptible to sql injection.  Always use binding/parameterized queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To store double quotation marks or any other special character, use a parameter to pass the string into the SQL statement ([as suggested by CL in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179334/ios-how-to-insert-special-like-or-character-in-sqlite/19180653#19180653)):

```
NSString *str = @"some characters \" and \'";
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable(Name) VALUES(?)";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"SQL execution failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"SQL prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Hope this will help you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: if i want to update an existing value in db using a string which contains special characters like " and '. how to do it?

Comment: it works but what about delete that string by identifying object with that string only unable to delete it . Any Solution ???????

Answer (score 4):

You can replace all double quote occurrences in SummaryDescription calling this:

```
NSString *newSummaryDescription = [SummaryDescription stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```

So you code will look like this:

```
NSString *newSummaryDescription = [SummaryDescription stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE tablename SET SummaryDescription=\"%@\" WHERE SummaryDate1=\"%@\" AND ClientId=\"%@\"", newSummaryDescription, [_dic objectForKey:@"SummaryDate1"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ClientID"]];
```

Comment: This did not work for me. What worked was to use stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""]. I.e. two double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Escape(/)** the quotation mark.

Like :

`hai "Man" :` >> **To** >> `: hai \""Man\""`