# sqlite3 WHERE statement issues

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

```
[self openDB];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *set = [defaults stringForKey:@"defaultSet"];
if ([set length] > 0) {
    NSString *trySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT setName FROM setData WHERE setName = `%@`", set];
    sqlite3_stmt *tryStatement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [trySql UTF8String], -1, &tryStatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"set here");
    } else {
        NSAssert(0, @"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}
```

So I return an error of `reason: 'no such column: set'`

Now, this is how I would normally write except I would use a PDO:: technique for .php but in objective c it's somewhat different. I'm not sure whether I'm using it correctly.

Do I need to bindValue of some sort, or am I trying to find a column name with a row name and/or..?

Comment: Looks like the wrong type of quotes in your value, but indeed do use bind parameters.

Comment: @Mat It appears the simple trick of changing quotes fixed my issue, I could then check for rows to determine whether the nsdefault was still appropriate. Such a simple fix to an hours headache! Thank you, if you post an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Aha, you can post your own answer as well if @Mat don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backticks are used to quote column names.
(SQL actually uses double quotes, backticks are supported only for compatibility with MySQL.)

In SQL, strings are quoted with straight single quotes:

```sql
... WHERE `SomeColumn` = 'SomeString'
```

In any case, you should [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24887255/11654) instead.

Comment: Too much MySQL  drilled into my brain I think, Thanks a bunch, ( not saying it was the correct approach for mysql btw )