# insert data into table giving syntax error SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sqlite

i am getting data from API and here is my response

```
{
author = "Joanne Chiu";
description = "Asian stock markets tumbled Wednesday following overnight declines in the U.S. and Europe. Key markets including Japan, Hong Kong and mainland China fell more than 1.5%. Japan\U2019s Nikkei average shed 1.7% to hit a six-week low, while South Korea\U2019s KOSPI slipped\U2026";
publishedAt = "2018-05-30T05:04:26Z";
source =     {
    id = "the-wall-street-journal";
    name = "The Wall Street Journal";
};
title = "Asian Stocks Down, Following Global Concerns Over Italy's Political Turmoil";
url = https://www.wsj.com/articles/asian-stocks-down-following-global-concerns-over-italys-political-turmoil-1527656546;
urlToImage = https://images.wsj.net/im-12406/social;}
```

i want to store all data into database..here is my query

```
let query : NSString = NSString(format: "insert into newsData (sourceName, authorName, title,  description, url, urlToImage, publishedAt) values (%@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@)", sourceName, authorName, title, description, url, urlToImage, publishedAt)
```

but it gives me a syntax error

> Error executing query 'near "Wall": syntax error'

i thought it was because of special character "-" so removed it but still it is giving me same error

Comment: seem like you want to insert double quote in database. try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887000/how-to-store-double-quotation-marks-in-sqlite-using-ios

Comment: try this String(format:"INSERT INTO newsData (sourceName,authorName,title,description,url,urlToImage,publishedAt) VALUES (\’%@\’,\’%@\’,\’%@\’,\’%@\’,\’%@\’,\’%@\’,\'%@\')”,, sourceName, authorName, title, description, url, urlToImage, publishedAt)

Comment: Your strings need to be quoted, ie `'%@'` - probably also want to escape the text to double quote the quote marks (`'`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer works fine thank you